# Using a 276-640 instead of a tsop 1236

Tags: capacitor, resistors, infrared, wiring

I'm trying to use a 276-640 instead of a tsop 1236. I heard that it will still work. I can't find any datasheets for the 276-640. In the tsop 1236 datasheet, is the picture below. Does this apply to the 276-640 as well? I'm guessing that the 276-640 is newer and maybe better designed so that it doesn't need the capacitor and resistor shown in that picture.

[image]

Comment: What is a 276-640? Make and Model will help.

Comment: @Dean - it's a IR-receiver module offered by Radio Shack. 276-640 is the catalog number. The Radio Shack website doesn't give details about make or type. And apparently 200ok404notfound doesn't understand that you can't produce a datasheet if you don't know the type...

Comment: @Stevenvh I do agree with you comment you make on your answer that components without datasheets are useless.

Answer (score 2):

You won't find a datasheet for a `276-640` because it's not a manufacturer's part number, it's a Radio Shack catalog number. I find components without datasheet pretty useless.

I wouldn't call Radio Shack *avant garde* when it comes to offering newer parts. I think Vishay's parts are well up-to-date. For instance, all recent parts work with voltages down to 2.5V.
Even so, the capacitor is always recommended, no matter how new the receiver is. If you don't place it the receiver will cause minor spikes on Vcc.

Another note on the `276-640`: keep in mind it has a carrier frequency of 38kHz, whereas for the TSOP1236 this is 36kHz. Things you'll find in the datasheet... (at least for the TSOP1236, for the `276-640` you can find this information on Radio Shack's webpage, but there's no other info than that...)

Comment: So where's the datasheet?

Comment: Did you downvote me because I can't produce a datasheet for something which isn't even a part number, let alone that we know who's the manufacturer??

Comment: @stevenvh  I upvoted you cuz I thought your use of "Radio Shack" and "Advant Garde" in the same sentence was inspired.

Comment: The tsop 1236 is an old part. It can't operate with anything below 4.5V. The Radio Shack equivalent has been discontinued and has been replaced with the 276-640 which can operate with as little as 2.7V.

Comment: @200ok404notfound - Not true. [this datasheet](http://www.vishay.ru/docs/82013/tsop12xx.pdf) for the TSOP1236 says minimum 2.5V. BTW, how do you know about the 276-640 being 2.7V? Did you find a datasheet?

Comment: It says 2.6V on the package.